# How does UPS WorldShip know if Internet Explorer launched?

Tags: c, internet-explorer, communication

We use Aurora as a browser, but UPS WorldShip stubbornly uses Internet Explorer. So I created an executable named `iexplore.exe` and replaced the real `iexplore.exe` with my "fake". My "fake" `iexplore.exe` just launches Aurora. So I fire up WorldShip, and click `UPS Home Page` (or something like that) and it launches Aurora. But then WorldShip hangs, saying `Connecting... Please Wait` as though nothing launched.

My question is: How does IE communicate with WorldShip to let it know that IE has launched?
How can I implement this in my own program (preferably in C)?

**EDIT**
IE is started with the `-Embedding` option. Anyone know what that does?

Comment: You can try to fool the web server by spoofing the User-Agent. Try the [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) addon for that. However, like @rekire stated, if the web site is doing something that is truly IE only, it still won't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Explorer is detected by the [User-Agent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.43) in the HTTP header (as defined in the [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)). So if your browser don't send "MSIE" somewhere in the User-Agent, UPS won't think that you use an Internet Explorer.

Depending on the API that UPS uses it is possible that you really need to use the IE, especially if ActiveX is used. This is not supported by any other browser.

Comment: I am talking about the UPS WorldShip program. There is a menu item that opens a browser, and I am trying to make UPS WS open firefox instead of IE. The website **does** work with firefox. Do I make myself clear?

Comment: There are several options how the ie is lunched. Did you try put an InternetExplorer.exe in the same directory like that ups tool? Which prints out for debugging just the command line? Please note that your test programm must not exit itself, wait for a keypress or so. If your exe gets excecuted please add to your question the command line. (But you should censor critical data.)

Comment: UPS WS looks for `iexplore.exe` in the `Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer`. But I never thought of trying to find the command line. I'll try that, and post the results.

Comment: The **-embedding** command-line option means *Starts Windows Internet Explorer through OLE embedding (such as the WebBrowser Control)* from the [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025.aspx).